# Find Object in List<object> by same property

Tags: c#, linq

I'm creating a list with different objects `List<object>` and I need to use linq on them.

All objects have a **"name" property** , Here's some class objects :

```
   class project_node
    {
        public string name { get;set;  } // SAME
        public int level{ get; set; }
        public compiler_enum compiler{ get; set; }
    }

   class resource_node
    {
        public string name { get;set;  } // SAME
        public int level{ get; set; }
        public byte[] resource_data { get; set; }
        public compiler_enum compiler{ get; set; }
    }

   class codeblock_node
    {
        public string name { get;set;  } // SAME
        public string filename{ get;set;  }
        public int level{ get; set; }
        public string code{ get; set; }
        public compiler_enum compiler{ get; set; }
    }
```

So my list has some project_node , some resource_node and some codeblock_node...

Declaration of `project_file_list` :

```
List<object> project_file_list = new List<object>{};
```

How can I use linq to find and match name in my list ?
something like this :

```
object find_target = project_file_list.Find(findobj => findobj.name == "Name");
```

Comment: Whats wrong with the code you have.

Comment: @TheGeneral `findobj` doesn't has `name` property.

Comment: Please show the declaration of `project_file_list`

Comment: @TheGeneral Added.

Comment: `List<object>` is seldom a good way of storing anything, if you need to query on a property maybe its best in the case to make an interface for those properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an interface, something like this:

```
interface IHaveName 
{
    string name {get;}
}
```

Then, all your objects can implement this interface:

```
class project_node: IHaveName
{ … }
```

And your list should be a List of IHaveName instead of List of object

```
List<IHaveName> project_file_list = new List<IHaveName>
… etc...
```

and your LINQ will work.

Comment: Sometimes I feel too stupid :( ! Thank you and Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making a list of generic object you wouldn't be able to get into the corresponding property like you usually do.

You could do something like this:

```
class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

var items = new List<object>()
{
    new B { Name = "B", Value = 1 },
    new B { Name = "A", Value = 2 }
};

var target = new A { Name = "A", Score = 1 };

object match = items
.Find(o => o.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(o) == target.Name ); 
//Here would be your object
```